# Best way to add things above and under a RecyclerView?

Tags: android

i'm making an app for my sociall media website, nothing really special.
By the user pages, i want to show their username, profile picture, status ect ect. Below that, i have a RecyclerView that displays all their posts.
When i scroll down, i want the user info to move away to above, so the recyclerView is full screen. And when you scroll back to the top, that the info will be there again. A similar thing what for example Instagram has on their user pages.
I already tried an scrollview, but i coudn't get it to work.
Hope you guys can help me out?

Comment: Try CoordinatorLayout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Thanks for replay, tried serveral things, but coudnt get it to work. Do you maybe have a tutorial or something?

Comment: This is a good article, check it out http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: In your case the recyclerView will have this attribute app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Thank you man <3, i will check that one out, and see if it solves the problem.